# Antd beforeUpload does not work as expected with different file formats

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using simple antd Uploader dragger component and passing props beforeUpload as well to avoid uploading file extensions that I do want to get uploaded. The code is below:

```
const props = {
    name: "file",
    multiple: true,
    action: "/upload",
    beforeUpload: (file) => {
         if (file.name.split(".").reverse()[0] !== ("pdf" || "doc" || "docx")) {
            console.log(`${file.name} is not a correct format file`);
         }
         return file.name.split(".").reverse()[0] === ("pdf" || "doc" || "docx") ? true : Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
              },
     onChange(info) {
        const { status } = info.file;
         console.log(info.files) //All format files are shown in console
      },
      accept: ".pdf,.doc,.docx",
      showUploadList: false,
      fileList: files,
};
```

This is return of component

```
<Upload.Dragger {...props}>
  <p>Drag and upload your files</p>
</Upload.Dragger>
```

The issue is that even though the console works and shows that a particular file is not a correct format file, it still gets added to the fileList array which it should not as I am using Upload.LIST_IGNORE with it. I ve been trying to debug since hours but no use, can anyone please guide me about the issue, I ll be grateful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Antd uploader accepting all files despite giving the accept prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66577093/antd-uploader-accepting-all-files-despite-giving-the-accept-prop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation, you are just comparing the file type of uploaded file with `pdf` type, as all your file formats are in the bracket and you are using `||` which will return the first truthy value, which is `pdf` in your case.

You need to check the uploaded file type with your accepted file formats list.

```
beforeUpload: (file) => {
 const acceptedFormats = ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx'];
 return acceptedFormats.includes(file.name.split('.')[1]) ? true : Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
},
```

Comment: Even with this, png and other format files are being added to the fileList array for some reason. And I am unable to understand this behavior.

Comment: Can you share the sandbox of your implementation.

Comment: I want to use it like this https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-and-drop-antd4131-forked-pj20u?file=/index.js This automatically caters the format issue and does not append wrong format files but when I copy the exact thing in my current application, it adds all format files in the fileList array.

Comment: If you add my code snippet in the sandbox, it is working as intended. It is not adding excluded file type to upload.

Comment: Yes but the exact same thing when I copy in my app, the behavior is different. Can it be because of version?

Comment: I am not sure of that. Just compare the version in sandbox with your local version, if this is what you think, and add packages of the exact version to verify it.

Comment: Can you solve the same issue again but with the older version, the issue comes when I downgraded the version I need to use in my project. Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-and-drop-antd4131-forked-pj20u?file=/index.js